# Selenium Webdriver - JMeter - shows lesser size at 'Size in bytes' on sampler compared to browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I have selenium webdriver configured on JMeter for testing an application from a front-end perspective. I am facing a challenge where the WebDriver Sampler is executing successfully and showing a size of 260KB. However, my page is around 2.5 MB. are there any additional settings required for enabling the measure to show a size of the complete page with resources?

Size of my Page on the browser: 2.5 MB
Size of just the HTML on the browser: 35 KB

What is reported on WebDriver sampler on Jmeter for the page with all resources: 260KB

I see that the whole page is getting loaded on the browser instance that Jmeter opens, but the size is always shown lesser.

[image: Image link here]

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [WebDriver Sampler source code](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/c736d275a60bb00dc960353f6eb6799e2b04d174/plugins/webdriver/src/main/java/com/googlecode/jmeter/plugins/webdriver/sampler/WebDriverSampler.java#L89)

```
res.setResponseData(getWebDriver().getPageSource(), null);
```

So basically JMeter reports the length of what [getPageSource()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/server/handler/GetPageSource.html) function returns, to wit main HTML without any embedded resources.

So I would recommend measuring the total response size basing on what [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler returns as identifying all "external" stuff like images, styles, fonts, scripts, etc. might be quite tricky. See [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses) article to learn more about configuring JMeter to behave like a real browser in terms of working with the "embedded resources"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Almost the same as what I thought, but wanted a confirmation as I did not look into the sampler code. I did validate the size through HTTP sampler and that gives only few resources compared to web browser because there are a bunch of js that gets executed on browser and request further more resources.

But your explanation on why I am seeing lesser size for WebDriver helps! Thanks again.